# Unable to install nginx in virtual box

Tags: apt, nginx

Hi I am trying to install `nginx` on my virtual linux ubuntu. I am using below command to install `nginx`.

```
sudo apt-get install nginx.
```

Whenever I execute this command I get the error below.

[image]

After looking into error message i can see some init system helpers needs to be updated as i am using older versions. So how can i update init system helpers?

Please help me in trying to figure it out the above error, thank you.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using older version of ubuntu then first upgrade your system
and after then install ngnix. 
update using `sudo update-manager -c` it will take 2 to 3 hrs depending on upgrade size.

Comment: Instead of that is it good to install with latest version of Ubuntu through virtual box? If yes please suggest me which version I should follow. Thank you

Comment: you can install ubuntu 16.04 LTS release or the latest ubuntu 17.10 latest release . any one will work smoothly . i will suggest you to  go with 16.04 lts

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop go this website and select 16.04.03 lts

Comment: I was using 14.04.2 version. So this is not going to support ngnix rigt?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the version of nginx you are trying to install is not compatible with your version of Ubuntu.

Specifically, it needs the version of libssl1.0.0 and init-system-helpers from xenial or higher but you have trusty or lower.

I would guess you are getting it from a third party repository so you can get a more recent version, but you need to ensure that it's backported to your Ubuntu version (ie, find one specifically compiled to work with the packages in your version of Ubuntu).  Otherwise, you either can't use it, or you'd have to start upgrading parts of your Ubuntu to a newer version.

Comment: Thanks. Please suggest me which version of Ubuntu I should install it in my virtual box? I am trying to deploy .net apps in Linux environment. Please suggest me which version of Ubuntu I should have. Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a separate question.  I don't know what your specific requirements are.

Comment: I am trying to deploy .net core in Linux. I was following http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2017/05/01/deploying-and-hosting-asp-net-core-applications-on-ubuntu-linux/&grqid=Q-wUkRYe&hl=en-IN and in middle I stucked